# Combobox combined from database: tkinter.TclError: Index 0 out of range and other error

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a simple combined combobox that pulls the data from the database Sqlite and Python 3.x. If I open the combobox1 "Nation/Country", as an example, I would like to display the relative cities in the cobobox2 "City".

I get this error

```
     return self.tk.call (self._w, "current", newindex)
_tkinter.TclError: Index 0 out of range
```

Even not getting it previously, the combo combobox didn't work well, because if i open England and receive London, Liverpool, Manchester, etc and i select other countries in the combobox1 "Nation/Country", I will always receive the cities of England. For example, I open France and still receive London, Liverpool, Manchester (not Paris, Marseille, Bordeaux, etc).

How can I solve? Can you show me the answer with my code please? I'm new to Python, if you only theoretically explain the problem to me I might not understand. Thanks

```
#combobox nation
lbl_Nation = Label(root, text="City", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="#a8dd71", fg="white")
lbl_Nation.place(x=6, y=60)

combo_Nation = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_Nation.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Nation.set("Select Nation")

def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nation FROM All_Nation')
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

combo_Nation['value'] = combo_nation()
combo_Nation.set("Seleziona")

############################################################### 
#combobox city
lbl_City = Label(root, text="City", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="white", fg="black")
lbl_City.place(x=6, y=110)

combo_City = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_City.place(x=180, y=110)
combo_City.set("Select City")

def combo_city():
    val = combo_City.get()
    cursor.execute('SELECT s.City FROM All_Nation s, All_Nation c WHERE s.ID_Nation=c.ID_Nation AND c.City = ?', (val,))
    result=[row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_City['value'] = result
    combo_City.current(0)
    return result

combo_City['value'] = combo_City()
combo_City.set("Select")


combo_Nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)
```

UPDATE N.1

```
CREATE TABLE "All_Nation" (
    "ID_Nation" INTEGER,
    "Nation"    TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID_Nation" AUTOINCREMENT)
);

CREATE TABLE "CITY" (
    "ID_City"   INTEGER,
    "City"  TEXT,
    "ID_Nation" INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY("ID_Nation") REFERENCES "All_Nation"("ID_Nation") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID_Sq" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: It is obviously that the SQL inside `combo_city()` returns no record.

Comment: @acw1668 How should I solve? I'm just starting out with Python. Could you show me through my code please? Thanks

Comment: You need to post the table definition of `All_Nation` table.  Also post some sample data of the table.

Comment: @acw1668 Ah OK. So the problem is SQL? Is all the rest of the code well written?

Comment: The rest of the code seems ok except `combo_city()` should accept an argument because `tkinter` will pass the `Event` object to the bind function.

Comment: @acw1668 While I search and place the data on the SQL (even if I think it is correct), can you show me how I can solve the combo_city () problem you are talking about? Thanks

Comment: You need to define `combo_city()` as `def combo_city(event=None):`.

Comment: @acw1668 I changed to def combo_city (event = None), but I still get the same error written above when I open the combobox. I updated the question by entering the database data. Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on provided table information, the SQL used inside `combo_city()` will returns no record.

Below is an example code based on posted one:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3

cnx = sqlite3.connect('nations.db')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

def combo_nation():
    cursor.execute('SELECT Nation FROM All_Nation')
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    return result

def combo_city(event):
    nation = combo_Nation.get() # get the selected nation
    cursor.execute('SELECT City FROM All_Nation n, CITY c WHERE n.ID_Nation = c.ID_Nation AND n.Nation = ?', (nation,))
    result = [row[0] for row in cursor]
    combo_City['values'] = result
    combo_City.set('Select City')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')
root.config(bg='white')

# Nation
tk.Label(root, text="Nation/Country", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="white", fg="black").place(x=6, y=60)

combo_Nation = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_Nation.place(x=180, y=60)
combo_Nation.set("Select Nation")

combo_Nation['values'] = combo_nation()
combo_Nation.set("Seleziona")
combo_Nation.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', combo_city)

# City
tk.Label(root, text="City", font=("Calibri", 11), bg="white", fg="black").place(x=6, y=110)

combo_City = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Calibri", 11), width=30, state="readonly")
combo_City.place(x=180, y=110)
combo_City.set("Select City")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are very nice. Now I "study" the code. What was the problem? Where was I wrong? Thanks. P.S: being new to this site, I have no reputation for voting for your answer, only for assigning the question as resolved